# What the word ほと means in 彼はほとそんなことを呟いた?

Tags: adverbs

What ほと means in 彼はほとそんなことを呟いた?

The full sentence is あの夕景色の流れは、さては時の流れの象徴であったかと、彼はほとそんなことを呟いた。

from the book 雪国

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is an old-fashioned way of saying "ふと".